# Application with GPS that consults a web service every X minutes

Tags: android, gps, android-service, battery

I'm try to build an application that runs in the background in my Android and every X time units sends the position to a remote web service that returns some data or null. It's necessary to send the position in every consult. It's necessary that the cellphone initialize the event.
The use case is that I'm walking in the city, and when I'm next to a point in the maps my cell  provides information about that place.

What is the best way to handle this that will not drain the battery?

My idea is run in the background the gps handler that every ten minutes gets the current position, and to have a service that sends the information to the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Much of this is with help from [Optimizing Battery Life](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html).

Essentially, the most important thing to do in optimizing battery life is to minimize the amount of times you request data, and to make all of the calls at about the same time. When you make a call, the radio turns on to high power for a few seconds after. 10 queries in a second is much better than 1 query every 6 seconds.

The same goes for the GPS. If you can life with only having updates every 10 minutes, that will greatly save time. My guess is that if your application only requires data at such infrequent intervals, you might use a coarse location, which will not require the use of the GPS antenna and thus further save battery power.